# How to open native emoji keyboard on button click - Android

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

I want to open native emoji keyboard.

How to do it?

i have tried using xml but i want it on button click

android:inputType="textShortMessage|textMultiLine"

Comment: you have to use your own emoji keyboard. What if some devices don't have emoji keyboard installed?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
android:inputType="textShortMessage|textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction"
```

in your edittext xml attributes

Comment: This is not working for me